# Python OpenCV imshow fails

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I installed opencv on my Ubuntu 14.04 system system with

```
pip install python-opencv
```

my Python version is 2.7.14

```
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

tells me that I have the OpenCV version 3.4.0.

After that I wanted to follow the tutorial on the OpenCV website

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
print img
```

It works fine until this point, but then I am supposed to enter

```
cv.imshow('image',img)
```

and I get the following error:

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x233cdb0) is not the object's thread (0x2458430).
Cannot move to target thread (0x233cdb0)

QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x233cdb0) is not the object's thread (0x2458430).
Cannot move to target thread (0x233cdb0)

QPixmap: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: what does "print img" show?

Comment: Unrelated :  why 2.7? why not 3.6.x ?

Comment: Try `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`.

Comment: @jms print img shows the rgb values

Comment: @Thomas Kühn this doesnt appear to change anything

Comment: @Peter111 ok, was just a guess.

Comment: You should install OpenCV in the proper way, the python-opencv is not officially from OpenCV

Comment: what happens if you do 'cv.namedWindow("image")'

Comment: If you haven't installed opencv from source it might have created a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently

```
pip install python-opencv
```

is not working at all and should not be used. After I installed Opencv from their website it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if the image you are reading is loading

```
image = cv2.imread(filepath,0) #0 for gray scale
if image is None:
    print "Cant Load Image"  
else:
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

seems hard to install opencv on ubuntu, I finally get it with a docker image

https://hub.docker.com/r/jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv/

or you can download sources and make install as described on
 https://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/ using bash script